# CSS nested nth-child() is acting weird

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to create a simple 3x3 grid (using `<table>`) with all cells having a `1px` border. If I simply use CSS to give all `<td>` elements a `1px` border then the inner borders will stack and create `2px` border so I'm treating each `<td>` differently. I have succeeded in doing it that way and used `nth` child to reduce the CSS. However, my question is why a certain logical way that uses even less CSS selectors doesn't work.

Here is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>3x3 grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS that works:

```
td{
    border: 1px #000;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
}
tr:nth-child(2) td{
    border-top: 0px;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td{
    border-top: 0px
}
td:nth-child(1){
    border-right: 0px;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    border-left: 0px;
}
table{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Here is the CSS that uses one less selector and should work but somehow all upper cells end up with no top borders.

```
td{
    border: 1px #000;
    border-top: 0px;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
}
tr:nth-child(1) td{
    border-top: 1px;
}
td:nth-child(1){
    border-right: 0px;
}
td:nth-child(3){
    border-left: 0px;
}
table{
    border-spacing: 0px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

I tested it with both Safari and Firefox. Also please tell me if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6):

The reason you have no top border on your `td`'s is because you aren't declaring a `border-style` or `border-color`...

```
tr:nth-child(1) td{
    border-top: 1px;
}
```

should be...

```
tr:nth-child(1) td{
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
}
```

You could simplify this greatly by just using `border-collapse: collapse`

```css
td{
    border: 1px #000;
    width:30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
}

table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but `td`'s in first row have changed from solid to none. Try using:

```
tr:nth-child(1) td{
    border-top: solid black 1px;
}
```

in CSS and should be right. http://jsfiddle.net/u1d1ctcy/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do that by below code only :

```
<style>
    table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
          }

    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid black;
         }
 </style>
```